# Error in multiplying each element in list, inside 2D array

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

Quick question about multiplying elements inside a list:

I have a list with 5 lists inside a list, containing two float values each.

```
str_list = [[-8.0, 0.070879], [-67.0, 0.263145], [92.0, 0.034718], [19.0, 0.231517], [35.0, 0.399741]]
```

Now, I am trying to multiply each of these elements by themselves, and then print them into a list containing the 5 variables that have been multiplied:

```
num_list = [-0.567032, -17.630715, 3.194056, 4.398823, 13.990935]
```

Here is the code that I am using, but the output is not the one desired above.

```
num_list = []
for pair in str_list:
        for x in pair:
            product = 1
            product = product * x
            num_list.append(x)
```

The result I am getting is

```
[0.070879, 0.263145, 0.034718, 0.231517, 0.399741]
```

which means that the program is only taking the second half of my lists and not actually multiplying anything.

It seems like a very basic error that I cannot see. Thank you for the help.

Comment: `num_list = [x[0] * x[1] for x in str_list]`

Comment: @Nick, yes, this seemed to have fixed it, thank you

Comment: That is **not** the output of the code you provided. Basically your code flattens the list.

Comment: _The result I am getting is_ The output I get is different, can you clarify things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Liner in Python using list comprehension (If your inner list will always have only two integers):

```
str_list = [[-8.0, 0.070879], [-67.0, 0.263145], [92.0, 0.034718], [19.0, 0.231517], [35.0, 0.399741]]

print([i[0]*i[1] for i in str_list])
```

Outputs:

```
[-0.567032, -17.630715000000002, 3.194056, 4.398823, 13.990935]
```

One Liner using `functools` (handles any number of integers in your inner list):

```
from functools import reduce
num_list = [reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, i) for i in str_list]
print(num_list)
```

Your code has alot of issues. The issues are listed below:

1. variable `product` should be moved from inner for loop to outer for loop as it it being reinitialized to 1 for every element of a pair in your list.
2. You should append `product` not `x` in your `num_list`.
3. You should append the product in your outer for loop (not in your inner for loop)

The right way to do it:

```
num_list = []
for pair in str_list:
        product = 1
        for x in pair:
            product *= x
        num_list.append(product)

print(num_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken for logic.

```
num_list = []
for pair in str_list:
    product = 1
    for x in pair:
        product = product * x
    num_list.append(x)
```

Thanks